# While sharpeoint product configurationi get this error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

> An exception of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown. 
>   Additional exception information: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OpenConnection()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData,
>   Boolean retryForDeadLock)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, Boolean retryForDeadLock)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPLock.ReleaseStaleLock(SqlSession
>   sqlsession, Int32 timeoutInSeconds)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPLock.CleanupStaleSession()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.AcquireFarmUpgradeLock(Boolean
>   bForce, Boolean singleClickInstall)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.InitializeTask.Run()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Comment: add more detail about your action...what u doing and on which step this error occurred? SharePoint version etc.

Comment: Iam trying to run the sharepoint configuration wizard and this error occured

Answer (score 2):

typically this error indicates couple of things.

- Check if you can connect to the SQL server from SharePoint Server, looks like issue with connection.
- Make sure ports are open between SharePoint and SQL server
- Also Make sure the account running the config wizard has proper permission on SQL server
- also make sure SQL server is up and running, may be try to reboot it.
- SQL Server and SQL Server Browser services are running on SQL box.